# What is the difference between integrity, attribute, and table constraints using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, attributes, constraints, integrity

I have an assignment to complete where I have two questions that I am struggling to understand the difference between some terminology. I have emailed my lecturer to confirm but no response for a week and it's due in a few days!

First question asks me to create a table using an SQL command including data types and integrity constraints.
I understand an integrity constraint to be foreign keys, primary keys, unique, and not null. Please correct me if wrong.

Then the second question asks me to change the definition of this table by adding both an attribute constraint and a table constraint. 
I think that DROP/ALTER count as attribute constraints. But I have no idea what a table constraint is!

I also need to include on delete/on update for the foreign keys, but I am unsure whether this is part of integrity constraints or attribute/table constraints, and internet searches have proved fruitless so far.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that I'm really familiar with all this terminology.  However, the following is reasonable speculation.

- *Attribute constraints* would be on individual columns in a table.  Hence, this would logically include `NOT NULL` and `check` constraints.
- *Integrity constraints* would be on columns *between* tables.  Hence this would logically include `foreign key` constraints.
- *Table constraints* would be on all the rows in a table.  Hence, this would logically include `unique` constraints.

By this definition, a primary key would be both a table constraint (uniqueness) and an attribute constraint (not null).

Of the three, "integrity" constraints is rather commonly used.  I'm not overly familiar with the terminology on "attribute constraints" and "table constraints".

I would hope that the book, article, or lecture notes would clarify such a terminology issue.

Comment: You would hope so wouldn't you, but the lecture notes all just say 'constraints' and the assignment brief is the first time we've seen "attribute constraints" and "table constraints" used! Thankyou for the tips

Comment: @J.M . . . The important notion is to understand "within a row", "within a table", and "between tables".  Names can be important, but the native SQL names ("check", "foreign key", "not null", etc.) are more practical and useful for communication purposes.